# xsd classes have duplicate attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, winforms, xsd.exe

I have an `xml` file that I converted to an `.xsd` file with `xsd.exe file.xml /classes` then that file I created an `.cs` file with this command `xsd.exe file.xsd /classes /enableLinqDataSet` and first I imported only the `file.xsd` in a windows forms application and worked properly, I noticed that in the `file.cs` it automaticly added the `namespace TEST{}` also in the `file.designer.cs` `namespace TEST{//code//}` but when I tried to upload the same `file.xsd` in an `ClassLibrary` tried to add the correct namespace to the files like: `namespace TEST.ClassLibrary{}` and `namespace TEST.ClassLibrary{//code//}` but I can't see my `file.cs` in my project and if I surround the `file.cs` with the namsepace I get this errors:

```
Error   8   Duplicate 'global::System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute' attribute 23  6   Nop.Plugin.Misc.DobaImport
Error   6   Duplicate 'global::System.Serializable' attribute 19    6   Nop.Plugin.Misc.DobaImport
Error   7   Duplicate 'global::System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute' attribute Nop.Plugin.Misc.DobaImport
```

if I comment those attributes it builds correct but when I run it I get this message:

```
Only XmlRoot attribute may be specified for the type Nop.Plugin.Misc.DobaImport.XmlHelpers.lists. Please use XmlSchemaProviderAttribute to specify schema type.
```

Comment: It is highly unlikely that an XSD automatically generated from a single instance XML will be suitable for any other instance documents. Treat the generated XSD as a shortcut to starting with a blank document and correct the assuptions that `xsd.exe` has made about the structure of the document. Once you have a working XSD consider further steps.

Comment: but the same file.xsd has worked for a windows forms application, I think this is a namespace problem

Comment: I found the problem, I adding the file.xsd into a folder and the namespace was projectname.folder I tried to add the file.xsd into the root project and worked.